# R: Assigning manual colors in ggplot limits itself to few colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

I want to assign specific colors to my barplot per group, with ggplot2.

```
kombi2 <- data.frame(Klimatop1,Nutzung=rep(Innenstadtdf[,1],6),GV_Anteil1,Farben=rep(Nutzfarben,6))
p <- ggplot(data=kombi2,aes(x=Klimatop1,y=GV_Anteil1,fill=Nutzung))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
p+scale_fill_manual(values=kombi2$Farben)
```

When taking the default assignment,
[I get a wide color range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC2jK.png).
However I need to assign group-based colors manually. When I do that with `scale_fill_manual()` and the corresponding vector, [I get only 8 different colors in the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMOpG.png), which isn't enough for my 22 different groups.
This is some example code which gives the same color problem as the above code:

```
Nutzfarben1 <- c("#333333","#FFCC00","#FF6666","#33FFFF","#FFFFFF","#00FF33","#99CC00","#FF9933","#66CC00","#CC0033","#FFFF00","#666600","#999999","#99FF00","#0033CC","#CCCCCC","#333300","#CC9900","#99CC99","#006633","#FFCCCC","#993366")
Nutzfarben <- c("dimgray","darkorange","deeppink","aquamarine","floralwhite","springgreen4","green3","lemonchiffon2","moccasin","firebrick3","goldenrod1","palegreen4","lightslategray","lawngreen","cyan4","azure3","darkolivegreen","lightsalmon4","mediumseagreen","forestgreen","bisque","darkorchid")
df <- data.frame(one=rep(c(1:22),6),two=rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v"),6),three=1:132, Farben=rep(Nutzfarben1,6))
g <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=one,y=three,fill=two))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
g+scale_fill_manual(values=df$Farben)
```

I already tried it with some made up data, I also tried assigning the data as a hex rgb vector, as well as with r color names, and with all packages except ggplot2 not loaded.
Do you have another idea? Did I miss to set a value? Do I need another package? Could my problem be outside R? I use R version 3.5.1 with RStudio 1.1.453

Comment: You need to use a named vector in `scale_fill_manual()`. First run `names(Nutzfarben1) <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v")` then run `g+scale_fill_manual(values=Nutzfarben1)`

Comment: Also, just as an unrelated FYI, you can use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(stat="identity")`. Saves some typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the color palette to `palette(Nutzfarben)` does the trick!
For completeness: It's also important to use the simple vector in `p+scale_fill_manual(values=Nutzfarben)` instead of referring to the column containing the color assignment per row `p+scale_fill_manual(values=Farben)`.
So the code must be changed changed into this:

```
Nutzfarben <- c("dimgray","darkorange","deeppink","aquamarine","floralwhite","springgreen4","green3","lemonchiffon2","moccasin","firebrick3","goldenrod1","palegreen4","lightslategray","lawngreen","cyan4","azure3","darkolivegreen","lightsalmon4","mediumseagreen","forestgreen","bisque","darkorchid")
palette(Nutzfarben)
kombi2 <- data.frame(Klimatop=Klimatop1,Nutzung=rep(Innenstadtdf[,1],6),GV_Anteil=GV_Anteil1,Farben=rep(Nutzfarben,6))

p <- ggplot(data=kombi2,aes(x=Klimatop,y=GV_Anteil,fill=Nutzung))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity",colour="white")
p+scale_fill_manual(values=Nutzfarben)
```

Using a named vector was not necessary.
Thank you to @aosmith for providing the `palette()` hint.

Comment: Glad you figured things out!  I thought the info I dug up useful in figuring out why things were turning out so oddly but wasn't sure if it was a stand-alone answer.  You could add some of the info to your answer for posterity and then go ahead and accept your solution to wrap things up.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the issue is, but it doesn't make much sense to me why this error occurs. Always make sure you run `str()` on your data frame to understand the data.

even though you repeated a character vector into your data frame, it was coerced into a Factor with 22 levels.

If you run `as.character()` on `df$Farben` either before you call ggplot or right in `scale_fill_manual` it should fix the issue.

But again, I do not understand why ggplot does this when you pass a Factor vector as opposed to character vector, probably something to do with what argument `values` expects to be passed to it.

Comment: A factor is an integer under the hood, and it is these integers that the plot is using; try `values = 1:22` and see similar results.  The integers refer to the index of the default color palette, which turns out only has 8 colors in it.  You can see the default palette via `palette()`.  I hadn't run into this before but found info about this [here](http://stat545.com/block018_colors.html#basic-color-specification-and-the-default-palette) and [here](http://www.melissaclarkson.com/resources/R_guides/documents/colors_Ver2.pdf).